# custom layout settings won't apply

Tags: magento

I have small problem with Magento. I'm not Magento guru but i'm trying to figure out this error.

And this 1column page won't be 1 column, it always two-column. Where can i check it?

I set in admin to this page custom layout - 1 column and for all others - use parent settings, on root category i set 2 column with left pad - no luck.

Inside theme/package/layout/local.xml the template for catalog pages was set to:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">  
    <reference name="root">  
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>  
</reference>
```

For this one page the settings on admin was set to: Page Layout: 1 column.

These settings are not stable. In case the page is reloaded several times in a row, sometimes, I see, that the template for this page is "2-columns-left.phtml", sometimes - it is correct and is "1column.phtml"

Please i'll be glad for any help.

Edited:
How can i set this page to be always 1 column?
I've tried to comment template section in local.xml and setup Catalog->Manage categories->My_category->Custom design->Page layout to "1 column" but page still be sometimes loaded 1 column and sometimes 2 columns.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more clear. What are you asking, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the complete tutorial on http://www.exinent.com/magento-custom-theme-development/

Comment: When adding an external source/tutorial, please add the most relevant parts in the answer just in case the link goes down.

Answer (score 0):

1. please check if you don't have template set in cms: go to admin>`Catalog`>`Manage Categories`> [select your category] > `Custom Design` Tab > `Page Layout` - change to No layout updates
2. `catalog_category_layered` mostly is set if you have anchored category, check this, also try `catalog_category_default` handler

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to change the custom layout settings for the category page.

Go to admin panel Catalog > Manage Categories > Edit any category > Custom Design > Page Layout.

Here you can change the page layout for the category page.

Comment: Yes, i know.But it seems that this setting doesn't apply every time. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: If you have any cache enabled on your site then try to clear cache and check whether its working or not.